# Margin does not impact in "include"

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a view with articles. It uses "include", and I'm trying to make a little margin between them. However, "android:layout_marginTop" does not seem to have any impact on the layout.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    
    <include android:id="@+id/article1" layout="@layout/mainarticle" />
    <include android:id="@+id/article2" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" layout="@layout/article" />
    <include android:id="@+id/article3" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" layout="@layout/article" />
    <include android:id="@+id/article4" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" layout="@layout/article" />
    <include android:id="@+id/article5" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" layout="@layout/article" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You should add the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes in the `include` tag. Otherwise, the margins are not taken into consideration.

> However, if you want to override layout attributes using the `<include>` tag, you must override both `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` in order for other layout attributes to take effect.

https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include

Comment: strange, but true .. thnx

Comment: This only works if the include-xml itself doesn't have the merge-tag as root-element, see my answer below.

Comment: Still the same. Margins are not applied using include inside `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem and the answer from Kamen Goranchev doesn't work for me.

I have used ADT's feature "Extract include..." from the layout editor to extract some commonly used badges as a list of TextView-elements. So the Extract-include-tool wrapped my TextView-Elements in a **merge-tag**, which usually would be fine.

But, according to the very helpful sourcecode-link from boiledwater I see in line 888 https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#L888, the layout-attributes from the include-tag itself are only parsed if the include doesn't have the merge-tag as its root-element.

So I removed the merge-tag from the include and used another ViewGroup-tag like e.g. FrameLayout. Then the margins in the include-tag are working as expected.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for adding this special case.

Answer (score 8):

`include` tag support below properties:

1. Any android:`layout_*` attributes which you can overwrite.
2. `android:id` attribute.
3. `layout` attribute.
4. `android:visibility` attribute.

---

Etc:
    
    `include android:id=”@+id/news_title”
             android:layout_width=”match_parent”
             android:layout_height=”match_parent”
             layout=”@layout/title”/>`

Please read:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#L777

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, very helpful for my answer below! Upvoted your answer for it!

Answer (score 7):

Another solution would be to add `Space` before `include`:

```
    <Space
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 3):

must insert include into other layout.

e.g. Relativelayout

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/sub_edit_new_customer" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved the problem by adding some padding.

The layout you want to include:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"> <!-- add padding here -->

        <!-- your custom layout -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```