# Use margin on an include layout

Tags: android, android-layout, include

This is a follow up question to this question:

[Margin does not impact in "include"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947987/margin-does-not-impact-in-include)

I am trying to add a margin to an `include` layout. I have added `layout_width` and `layout_height` to the include element, but the margin is still ignored. Furthermore, when I try to auto complete the word "margin" in the layout xml file, this attribute is not even recognized.

So how can I add a margin to an `include` tag?

The layout:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/main_status"
     />

<!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
-->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

<!--
     android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
-->
<!--
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container.
-->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Comment: What about adding the margins **inside** the included layout (`@layout/article`)?

Comment: Could you share your xml?

Comment: the root element of the included layout is merge. I tried adding margin to it and it didn't work. I have also tried removing the merge element and set the margin on the next element which is a relativeLayout but it still did not work.

Comment: `the root element of the included layout is merge` What is **inside** `merge`? **This** layout can have its own margins.

Comment: @DerGol...lum but like I said, I tried removing the merge tag and add the margin on the inner root

Comment: You **don't have to remove** the `merge` tag! It's: `<merge  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"><YourLayout>...</YourLayout></merge>`

Comment: OK doing a margin on the inner layout works partially. The included layout is in the top of the containing layout, but doing margin bottom does nothing. and when I just set a margin, it pushes the included layout ON TOP of the other layouts without pushing the other layouts..

Comment: @DerGol...lum do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I see that both the LinearLayout and the fragment want a height of `match_parent`... which seems kind of a conflict, to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the LinearLayout's height is set to `match_parent`. I still want it like that, but that's what caused the included layout and container layout be on top of each other when trying to add margin inside the layout that I wanted to include.

So what I did that got me the effect I wanted was setting the `paddingTop` attribute of the linear layout container. It created some space between the included layout and the linear layout.